# Trying to import all functions from a file and storing them in a list

Tags: python, performance, testing, import

For context, I am trying to solve questions from a website, and for each question I am usually implementing 2-3 solutions via a function for each solution. I time each function using a timing wrapper, and I call each questions' solution python file from a global main.py. Now, what I am currently doing in the main.py is

```
from problem1 import func1, func2, func3
l = [func1, func2, func3]
for x in l:
    x(argument)
```

Now this works well given that I will always have 3 functions. But I want to be able to account for a variable number of functions without having to change the main everytime. I thought of just doing

```
from problem1 import * as func_list
for x in func_list:
    x(argument)
```

But this doesn't work as you can't import everything from a file/module under 1 variable.
Is there a solution for this problem or is my approach for the initial time testing situation itself completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can define `__all__` in your file

problem1.py

```
def func1(argument):
    pass


def func2(argument):
    pass


def func3(argument):
    pass


__all__ = [func1, func2, func3]
```

main.py

```
import problem1

l = problem1.__all__
for x in l:
    x(argument)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `dir()` function to get everything from inside a module you imported:

```
import problem1

d = dir(problem1)
for i in d:
    function = getattr(problem1, i)
    if callable(function):
        result = function("parameter")
```